# How to print an image to a Canvas belonging to another Windows 8.1 process?

Tags: c#, c++, canvas, directx, gdi

I have a C++ app and a Windows Forms C# app that communicate with each other over a socket bridge.  They are two separate Windows 8.1 executables (separate processes).  I would like to print an image from the C++ app to a Canvas belonging to a control residing on a form in the C# app.

The reason I want to print directly to a Canvas belonging to the C# app instead of shipping bitmaps around is performance.  The images I will be printing are frames coming in at 50 times a second from an attached camera.  Therefore, crunching the image from a Bitmap to a JPG and back the other way on the C# side with each socket transfer is a performance penalty I'd like to avoid.

As far as using a shared memory region goes, I've used them in the past but have had strange "glitches" I could never solve.  Also the huge number of soft errors that are inherent to that technique, due to the repetitive invalidation of the shared memory region's backing page with each write operation, look like hell in the Task Manager.

Since I control both code bases, it is easy for me to have the C# app pass O/S level elements (handles, etc.) to the C++ app needed to facilitate this.  Can anyone tell me what the general technique would be for me to do this?  I'm fine with using DirectX or the like if necessary.  But I need to know the general technique so I can get started.

Comment: It really would be a lot easier to put the bitmap (uncompressed) in shared memory. But even the socket isn't too bad. What kills you is the entirely useless JPEG step. Lossy compression is expensive, as it needs to carefully estimate what the human eye can't see.Just pass a bitmap directly over the socket, and besides being faster your image quality will be better.

Comment: @MSalters Any way to stop the huge number of "soft" page faults that pile up in the Task Manager, from constantly invalidating the backing page during a write operation to the shared memory area?

Comment: Is it backed by the page file, or by a physical file? Are you allocating new shared memory 50 times per second or reusing a single shared block?  There shouldn't be a soft fault for a page that's already mapped into the process.

Comment: @MSalters I believe I used the system swap file because it's supposed to be more performant.  Why wouldn't there be a soft page fault?  That's the technique the operating system uses for recognizing a changed page.

Comment: Yes, but that's only at the first change. The mapping is initially read-only, you write to it, get a soft page fault, and then the OS turns off the read-only bit and marks the page as "changed". If it ever writes the page to storage, the reverse is done. But if you reuse the same page - and that's why I asked whether you created 50 mappings per second - then the page will remain writeable after the first fault. Sure, an 1 MB bitmap will cause 250 faults, but not 250*50 per second.

Comment: @MSalters Interesting.  I believe you are indicating that I may have been accessing the shared memory page incorrectly, that somehow in the way I used it I was triggering a soft page fault on each additional write after the first one when that was unnecessary.  I'm a bit skeptical though because I noticed apps like Skype, which also use shared memory quite a bit due to the 3rd party Directshow capture filters it loads, have the exact same profile of having a huge number of soft page faults during operation (millions over time).  Still, definitely worth investigating.  Thanks.